# Why doesn't the Oculus test tool recognize my GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, oculus-rift

I have an Nvida GTX 670, but for some reason when I try the Oculus "is your PC ready for the Rift" test it only sees my integrated graphics chip?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/R2YdHHp.png]

When I look at my DirectX diagnostics it reports a GTX 670, and my games certainly don't run like they're on integrated graphics, so there shouldn't be any issue with the card itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The tool is likely running with your integrated graphics processor, rather than the Nvidia card. You can override this by:

1. `Right Click` the tool shortcut or executable
2. Go to `Run with Graphics Processor`
3. Click `High-performance NVIDIA processor`

After this, try running the tool again it it should report correctly.

[image: Run with Graphics Processor]

If you do not have the right click context menu, you can go into NVIDIA Control Panel, add the application under the `Manage 3D Settings` section, and force it to use the `High-performance NVIDIA processor` from here.

[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

Comment: I don't have the context menu item, and I also don't have that option in my Nvidia control panel. It is updated to the latest version. This is what it looks like http://i.imgur.com/4B6rFbv.png

Answer (score 0):

Optimus (the tech that switches between integrated and discrete graphics on most laptops) is not supported. Here's the reddit thread where Palmer Luckey makes that clear:
https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/3b8xxh/sdk_0601_win10_no_support_amd_no_extended_dx12_i/. If you don't have the preferred processor option maybe you actually don't have Optimus. Are you using a laptop? If not, what type of motherboard do you have?

In any case the minimum spec is a GTX 970 so you're going to need an upgrade.